# unable to copy node and it's sub-nodes using <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm trying to select a node that contains all of the sub-nodes AS IS using a xsl stylesheet. I have a section in my xml doc that contain a dynamic amount of sub-nodes, each with 2 pieces of data, and I just want to grab as they are in put them in my new xml doc (I am transforming other pieces of data in the xml doc).

here is my xml doc i'm trying to transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Active_Booking_Release_Report>
  <Inmate_Data>
      <bunch of fields i've already gotten to work />
      ....
   </Inmate_Data>
   <Charges_Data>
    <charge>
      <OffenseStatute>12345</OffenseStatute>
      <OffenseOffenseDescription>For Court Only</OffenseOffenseDescription>
    </charge>
    <charge>
      <OffenseStatute>67890</OffenseStatute>
      <OffenseOffenseDescription>For Court Only</OffenseOffenseDescription>
    </charge>
   </Charges_Data>
</Active_Booking_Release_Report>
```

and my stylesheet

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

      <!-- Match the root node -->
      <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy>
      <booking>
         <inmateData>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()|comment()"/>
         </inmateData>
      </booking>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

a whole bunch of statements for <Inmate_Data>

and the Charges section
<xsl:template match="//Active_Booking_Release_Report/Charges_Data">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and my desired output:

```
<booking>
   <inmateData>
      <transformed fields/>

      <charge>
      <OffenseStatute>12345</OffenseStatute>
      <OffenseOffenseDescription>For Court Only</OffenseOffenseDescription>
    </charge>
    <charge>
      <OffenseStatute>67890</OffenseStatute>
      <OffenseOffenseDescription>For Court Only</OffenseOffenseDescription>
    </charge>
   </Inmate Data>
</booking>
```

I'm loading and transforming the xml in a c# console app, and when I inspect the object containing the transformed data, everything is listed there except for the charges section.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly, you've got two template rules that match "/" and only one of them is going to match, and in XSLT 1.0 it's pretty implementation-dependent what happens when two templates match.

Secondly, your desired output isn't well-formed; I guess it was intended as a sketch, but it's not really clear what you wanted.

Thirdly, you haven't shown us the actual output.

Finally, you've left a whole load of your stylesheet code out: "a whole bunch of statements".

I'd suggest you fix the obvious error of the two duplicate template rules, then show us a complete listing of a runnable stylesheet, source document, and desired output, so we can actually see where you've gone wrong.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29789605)

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I disagree with your interpretation. I identified a bug in the supplied code that causes the supplied code to have undefined behaviour. In my book, that's an answer to the question.

Comment: you're right, i was trying to simplify things by just including what I thought were the pertinent parts, next time I'll post everything AS IS. The 2 template rules matching "/" was a typo on my part, again, I was trying to simplify things and only made them harder!  Anyways, I was able to trial and error my way to what I needed by using https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html. Should I just delete the question or is there a better way to close this out?